# Adding custom class to tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to style(css) some bootstrap-tooltip.js tooltips, without affecting all the tooltips. I have tried many different solutions but i allways end up adding a class to the element that triggers the tooltip.

This is what i tried:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id$=amount]").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'right'
  }).addClass("test"); // <--- This does not help me. Class just ends up 
});                    //      in the trigger element. Se html output 
                       //      from firebug below...
```

But then the class just ends up in the element that triggers the tooltips:

```
<input 
     id="list_wishes_attributes_0_amount" 
     class="test"  <!-- The class I tried to add to the tooltip ended up here. -->
     type="text" 
     tabindex="3" 
     size="30" 
     rel="tooltop" 
     name="list[wishes_attributes][0][amount]" 
     min="0" 
     data-original-title="Only numbers please"
/>
```

How can i assign a custom class for my tooltip, and not the input field that triggers it?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**(Updated March 23rd 2021 to include Boostap 5)**

**Prior to Bootstrap 4:**

```
$().tooltip({
  template: '<div class="tooltip CUSTOM-CLASS"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
})
```

---

**Bootstrap 4:**

```
$().tooltip({
  template: '<div class="tooltip CUSTOM-CLASS" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
})
```

---

**Bootstrap 5:**
They've added the ability to add the custom class within the source so its much easier to do.

```
$().tooltip({
  customClass: 'CUSTOM-CLASS'
})
```

**Pure Javascript:**

```
var exampleEl = document.getElementById('example')
var tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(exampleEl, {customClass: 'CUSTOM-CLASS'})
```

**or in the html:**

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" data-bs-custom-class="CUSTOM-CLASS" title="Some Helpful Info!" role="tooltip">Stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Weird that `template` isn't documented at all in the Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: You can give it as `data-template=""` attribute in the tag you attach tooltip to. It can give you trouble if you want to use that attribute for some other purposes.

Comment: class="arrow" to keep arrow in place in Bootstrap 4

Comment: `template: '<div class="tooltip  CUSTOM-CLASS"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"><div></div></div>'`
Bootstrap 4

Comment: Template is specified in the original docs, but it is fairly easy to miss. See under options: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options

Answer (score 25):

The method I use is to attach a class directly to the element via JQuery (works in Bootstrap 3). It's a little trickier, because you need to find the hidden, auto-generated element via the parent's `data` attribute.

```
$('#[id$=amount]')
  .tooltip()
    .data('bs.tooltip')
      .tip()
      .addClass('custom-tooltip-class');
```

I prefer this to overriding the template, because it's much more concise and less verbose than all that extra HTML.

Comment: Bets solution should be the approved one. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work in case the selector returns many tooltips (only works the 1st). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881679/1159167)

Comment: Only thing that worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

***(update: 21 Feb 2021)***

### Bootstrap 5

Custom classes can be used by adding the `customClass` option (in JS), or `data-bs-custom-class="..."`, in HTML, as described in the official documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#options

---

### Bootstrap 4 / Bootstrap 3

I've created a small extension for Bootstrap Tooltip plugin, which allows us to add custom classes for tooltips by using `customClass` parameter in Javascript or via `data-custom-class` attribute in HTML.

#### Usage

- via `data-custom-class` attribute:

`data-custom-class="tooltip-custom"` - builds a tooltip with the class `tooltip-custom`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-custom-class="tooltip-custom" title="Custom tooltip example">Tooltip example</button>
```

- via `customClass` parameter:

`customClass: 'tooltip-custom'`

```
$('.my-element').tooltip({
    customClass: 'tooltip-custom'
});
```

#### Setup:

The code differs depending on the Bootstrap version used (v3, v4-alpha or v4).

#### Bootstrap v4

**Javascript**

```
;(function($) {

  if (typeof $.fn.tooltip.Constructor === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap Tooltip must be included first!');
  }

  var Tooltip = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor;

  // add customClass option to Bootstrap Tooltip
  $.extend( Tooltip.Default, {
    customClass: ''
  });

  var _show = Tooltip.prototype.show;

  Tooltip.prototype.show = function () {

    // invoke parent method
    _show.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

    if ( this.config.customClass ) {
        var tip = this.getTipElement();
        $(tip).addClass(this.config.customClass);
    }

  };

})(window.jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip-custom .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.bs-tooltip-top .arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.bs-tooltip-right .arrow:before {
  border-right-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.bs-tooltip-left .arrow:before {
  border-left-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow:before {
  border-bottom-color: #5b2da3;
}
```

**Sass**

```
@mixin tooltip-custom($bg-color, $color: $tooltip-color) {

  .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: $bg-color;
    @if $color != $tooltip-color {
      color: $color;
    }
  }

  &.bs-tooltip-top .arrow:before {
    border-top-color: $bg-color;
  }

  &.bs-tooltip-right .arrow:before {
    border-right-color: $bg-color;
  }

  &.bs-tooltip-left .arrow:before {
    border-left-color: $bg-color;
  }

  &.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow:before {
    border-bottom-color: $bg-color;
  }

}
```

**Example**:
https://jsfiddle.net/zyfqtL9v/

**UPDATE January 8, 2020:
compatible with the latest Bootstrap version (4.4.1):**
https://jsfiddle.net/ep0mk94t/

---

#### Bootstrap v3.3.7

**Javascript**

```
(function ($) {

  if (typeof $.fn.tooltip.Constructor === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap Tooltip must be included first!');
  }

  var Tooltip = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor;

  $.extend( Tooltip.DEFAULTS, {
    customClass: ''
  });

  var _show = Tooltip.prototype.show;

  Tooltip.prototype.show = function () {

    _show.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

    if ( this.options.customClass ) {
        var $tip = this.tip()
        $tip.addClass(this.options.customClass);
    }

  };

})(window.jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip-custom .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.top .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.right .tooltip-arrow {
  border-right-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.left .tooltip-arrow {
  border-left-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #5b2da3;
}
```

**Example**:
https://jsfiddle.net/cunz1hzc/

---

#### Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6

**Javascript**

```
;(function($) {

  if (typeof $.fn.tooltip.Constructor === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap Tooltip must be included first!');
  }

  var Tooltip = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor;

  // add customClass option to Bootstrap Tooltip
  $.extend( Tooltip.Default, {
      customClass: ''
  });

  var _show = Tooltip.prototype.show;

  Tooltip.prototype.show = function () {

    // invoke parent method
    _show.apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

    if ( this.config.customClass ) {
      var tip = this.getTipElement();
      $(tip).addClass(this.config.customClass);
    }

  };

})(window.jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip-custom .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.tooltip-top .tooltip-inner::before, 
.tooltip-custom.bs-tether-element-attached-bottom .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-top-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.tooltip-right .tooltip-inner::before, 
.tooltip-custom.bs-tether-element-attached-left .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-right-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.tooltip-bottom .tooltip-inner::before,
.tooltip-custom.bs-tether-element-attached-top .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-bottom-color: #5b2da3;
}
.tooltip-custom.tooltip-left .tooltip-inner::before,
.tooltip-custom.bs-tether-element-attached-right .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-left-color: #5b2da3;
}
```

**SASS** mixin:

```
@mixin tooltip-custom($bg-color, $color: $tooltip-color) {
  
  .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: $bg-color;
    @if $color != $tooltip-color {
     color: $color;
  }
}

&.tooltip-top,
&.bs-tether-element-attached-bottom {
  .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-top-color: $bg-color;
  }
}

&.tooltip-right,
&.bs-tether-element-attached-left {
  .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-right-color: $bg-color;
  }
}

&.tooltip-bottom,
&.bs-tether-element-attached-top {
  .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-bottom-color: $bg-color;
  }
}

&.tooltip-left,
&.bs-tether-element-attached-right {
  .tooltip-inner::before {
    border-left-color: $bg-color;
  }
}
```

}

**Example**:
https://jsfiddle.net/6dhk3f5L/

Comment: This is excellent! Had to tweak to invoke the parent method after adding the class as in my case I was overriding the maximum width which messed with the placement. Other than that perfect!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879041/1159167) that works in case the selector returns many tooltips:

```
$("[id$=amount]")
  .tooltip()
  .each((i, el)=> $(el).data('bs.tooltip').tip().addClass('test'));
```

(*it should be OK for bootstrap 2 and 3*).

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom class/id in tool tip element as like :

```
<span class="red-tooltip" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title='Print wisely'>Here tooltip is needed</span>
```

Trigger the script as follows,

```
$('.red-tooltip').on('show.bs.tooltip', function(){
    $($(this).data('bs.tooltip').tip).addClass('yourclassname');
});
```

Add css properties for the class 'yourclassname'.

```
.redtooltip.tooltip > .tooltip-inner{
    background-color:#FF5257;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #FF5257 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help someone like it helped me:

Add a Custom class to your "generated" tooltip node:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-class").tooltip({
        tooltipClass:"my-custom-tooltip"
    });
});
```

Sample output as last child of body element:

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-1" role="tooltip" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content my-custom-tooltip" style="top: 295px; left: 908px; display: block;">
    <div class="ui-tooltip-content">My title contnet</div>
</div>
```

Applied to this questions logic:

```
$(function(){
  $("[id$=amount]").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'right'
    tooltipClass:'test'
  })
});
```

Tested using jQuery UI - v1.10.3

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `html` option to `true` and inserting something like `<span class="test">YOUR TEXT</span>` into the `title` option.

```
$(function(){
  $("[id$=amount]").tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    title: '<span class="test">YOUR TEXT</span>'
  });
});
```

I honestly am not sure if this will work, but I believe it's worth a shot.

**EDIT**: After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639708/modifying-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip-colors-based-on-position) it may be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I got a span with a class, like you suggested <span class="test">YOUR TEXT</span>, but I want to add a class to the parent div. The .tooltip div... I'm going to look trough the post you linked. I found some things there that seems promising :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I didn't have time to test it my self (currently at work), but let me know if you find a working solution =)

Answer (score 0):

Before the `.addClass`, try adding `.parent()` until you get the parent `div`.  Also - you could always use jQuery selectors to find the `div` you want and update the CSS from there.

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4, you can use following code to add different CSS classes on different tooltips:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('show.bs.tooltip', function() {
    let $tooltip = $($(this).data('bs.tooltip').tip);
    let customClass = $(this).attr('data-tooltip-css-class');

    if (customClass !== undefined) {
        $tooltip.addClass(customClass);
    }
});
```

Then, you will have a new attribute `data-tooltip-css-class` to add your custom classes:

```
<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-css-class="tooltip-large" data-placement="top" title="My tooltip">Example</span>
```

Attribute is not required and you can use it to add multiple classes.

**Example:**

```js
$(function() { 
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('show.bs.tooltip', function() {
        let $tooltip = $($(this).data('bs.tooltip').tip);
        let customClass = $(this).attr('data-tooltip-css-class');

        if (customClass !== undefined) {
            $tooltip.addClass(customClass);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.red-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    background: red;
}
.red-tooltip.bs-tooltip-top .arrow:before {
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-css-class="tooltip-large" data-placement="top" title="My tooltip">Classic tooltip</span>

<br><br>

<span data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-css-class="red-tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My tooltip">Custom tooltip</span>
```