# Custom templates for delegated Bootstrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using the Bootstrap tooltip plugin as suggested in [Adding custom class to tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160357/adding-custom-class-to-tooltip)

```
$('.tooltipped').tooltip({
    template: '<div class="tooltip foo-tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
});
```

However, I am using dynamic elements and so need to use it's delegated event functionality, as shown in [How do I bind Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958825/how-do-i-bind-twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-to-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.tooltipped',
    template: '<div class="tooltip thri-tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
});
```

Which then causes it to ignore the custom template... Why so?

Unfortunately I don't have the creds to comment on another post, so a new question it is...

Comment: Have you tried simple 'html' option? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage

Comment: You are absolutely correct... Schoolboy error! Thanks @keypaul

Comment: So it works with my tips?

Comment: Yes it does... Sorry for the delay...