# JSFiddle is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change a bootstrap tooltip color and here I've found a very promising answer for that:

[Change bootstrap tooltip color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color)

But, the JSFiddle quoted by Praveen Kumar is not working.

When I go mouseover Tooltip in bottom nothing happens, no tooltip appears.

Anyone knows why this JSFiddle is not working?

Comment: The external resources that the fiddle links to ``bootstrap.css`` and
``bootstrap-tooltip.js`` do not exist. Things have changed a lot since bootstrap 2.

Comment: You can find these resources on the side under "External Resources". [**Video demo**](http://screencast.com/t/CfKsscy8CAX). As the videos show, [bootstrap.css](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css) and [bootstrap-tooltip.js](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js) just forward to the front page of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the external resources have been moved. You can find these in the side of JSFiddle:

[image: External Resources JSFiddle]

Specifically the links have moved from/to:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css -> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css

and likewise

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js -> http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js

[**Here's the updated version of the Fiddle with the correct resource paths**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/16/)

```
I've also updated the original answer with the updated fiddle.
```

Comment: Nice work. Now I understand this Bootstrap issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing is  mentioned in `title` field and you need to add extra extensions i.e `jQuery UI 1.9.2`.Try this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
   title="hello" data-original-title="Tooltip on bottom"
   class="red-tooltip">Tooltip on bottom</a> 

<!--Title field was blank earlier.Now i added a text 'hello'-->
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/14/)

Comment: [Bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) =/= [jQuery UI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Comment: @what is sleep yup it does..:)

Comment: @h2ooooooo OP just wants to display tooltip regardless to whether it's jquery UI or bootstrap tooltip..

Comment: Thanks, Joke_Sense10, with Hello in the title it became "alive".

Comment: @M4i4 atleast jsfiddle is working now..:)