# Change color of tooltip on call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How would I change the color of a tooltip on JS call?

For example, taking the following:

```
$('a').tooltip();
```

And doing something like:

```
$('a').tooltip().css('background', 'red');
```

To change the tooltip's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

They say you can listen for when an element has one : Look under 'events'

```
$('a').on('show.bs.tooltip', function () {
   /* update - changing the tooltip background css */
   $(this).siblings('.tooltip > .tooltip-inner').css("background-color","red");

})
```

**Update :**

Or just setting in the CSS ( thanks to [Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color)  )

```
a + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: red'}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2.

Comment: It Works the same way in v2.3.2

Comment: @Walter Then why does your question have the `twitter-bootstrap-3` tag?

Comment: It's not working. It's changing the background color of the link (`a`) rather than the tooltip. :/

Comment: I see what you mean now @Walter. You confused me because you were trying to do this with js ( eq, why would you want to style a hidden tootip ? ) - for that you don't need js. You need to change the tooltip style class values in bootstrap.css

Comment: I've tried adding the class `.tooltip-white`, however, there's a problem. If I use `$('a').tooltip();`, it shows as white fine, but when I use `$('a').tooltip({ container: 'body' });`, it doesn't show as white (and I need to use `container: 'body'`.

Comment: `.a + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: red'} - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I just changed `container: 'body'` to a container that's more specific (like `container: '.box'`) and changed the css accordingly. Thanks. :)