# How to change the style/css of a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

first of all is this called a tooltip or am i on about something different?

anyway, i have managed to get a tooltip working as can be seen in the image link below. but the little box that pops up saying 'Password must be more than 6 characters' how do i target and hit this and change the style. so far i have either not been able to change it or the box i am hovering over is styled.

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=1fb09eb

here is some code:

html:

```
<label for="password">Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword" title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" ><br>
```

js:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "passwordTooltip"});
  });
  </script>
```

css:

```
[title]:after{
    background: #333;
}

[title]:hover:after{
    background: #333;
}
```

Comment: you have to use a custom javascript plugin to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to style default popup titles with some jQueryUI tooltip code? If you do, you must include the jQueryUI source files :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now you can add a `.tooltip` class (or use any other kind of selector) to those elements you want to have a styled tooltip for :

```html
<input type="password" id="pword" class="tooltip" title="Password must be more than 6 characters long">
```

```js
$('.tooltip').tooltip();
```

jQueryUI will automatically grab the `title` of each element and make it to the content of the styled tooltip. If you want to change the style of the tooltip, simply create a CSS class and initialise as above :

```css
.passwordTooltip {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```js
$('.tooltip').tooltip({
   tooltipClass: "passwordTooltip"
});
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/fsr9d7Le/**

Comment: it has deleted the input box for some reason and i have these lines of code:
`script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">` the smoothness is a later version isn't it? @davidkonrad

Comment: @ObeseOctopus -  deleted the input box? what browser are you using? AFAIK there is no correlation between jQueryUI versioning and jQuery. 1.11.4 is the latest version, should work with all jQuery +1.6 -> http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: ok something is seriously going wrong.
I have set my jsfiddle up exactly the same way you have, yet in mine..nothing happens https://jsfiddle.net/yu5hnxup/ what the heck!?

Comment: ok worked out that was to do with the external resources but now that i have added more code, it is not working... https://jsfiddle.net/yu5hnxup/4/

Comment: sorry for the bombardment of comments, i have now taken out external resources and put them in my code. the tooltip looks different, however, when altering the css it doesn't change it? https://jsfiddle.net/yu5hnxup/8/

Comment: @ObeseOctopus - have cleaned up your fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/yu5hnxup/17/ you had a lot of problems with inline links, double resources etc, but your major problem is that you are using **bootstrap and jQueryUI at the same time**!. That changes the picture dramatically. **You should not use both** - both have a `tooltip()`, thats why the input disappears. I would skip jQueryUI totally and style the boostrap tooltip instead -> [**Change bootstrap tooltip color**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17642447/1407478) (and more) - you can just delete comments you not want to stay.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small *VanillaJS* script to add support for custom tooltip styling.  It uses event delegation, so dynamically added elements with a `title` attribute should be scooped up and displayed properly.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var tooltipDelay = 500;
  var timer = null;

  document.body.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var el = e.target;

    if (el != document.body && (el.hasAttribute("title") || el.hasAttribute("data-styletip"))) {
      if (el.title) {
        el["tt-title"] = el.title;
        el["tt-show"] = function(pos) {
          var tip = document.createElement("div");
          tip.classList.add("style-tip");
          
          if (el.hasAttribute("data-styletip-class")) {
            tip.classList.add(el.getAttribute("data-styletip-class"));
          }
          
          tip.innerText = el["tt-title"];
          tip.style.zIndex = 9e9;
          tip.style.pointerEvents = "none";
          tip.style.position = "absolute";
          tip.style.left = pos.x + "px";
          tip.style.top = pos.y + "px";
          
          document.body.appendChild(tip);
          
          el["tt-tip"] = tip;
          this.addEventListener("mouseout", el["tt-destroy"]);
        };
        
        el["tt-destroy"] = function() {
          if (el["tt-tip"]) {
            document.body.removeChild(el["tt-tip"]);
            delete el["tt-tip"];
          }
        };
        
        el.removeAttribute("title");
        el.setAttribute("data-styletip", true);
      }

      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        el["tt-destroy"]();
        el["tt-show"]({
          x: e.pageX,
          y: e.pageY
        });
      }, tooltipDelay);
    }
  });

})();
```

```css
/* These styles get pretty close to the default Windows 7 tooltips */

.style-tip {
  font: 0.8em sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #eee);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.style-tip.red {
  background: linear-gradient(#fdd, #faa)
}

.style-tip.op-default {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p title="Normal tooltip&#013;With a linebreak!">Normal tooltip</p>
<p title="A red tooltip." data-styletip-class="red">Red tooltip</p>

<input type="password" id="pword" title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" placeholder="Input tooltip" data-styletip-class="op-default">
```

This should work as a drop-in script that "just works".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Style my tool tip plug in...

[Style-my-tooltips jQuery plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/style-my-tooltips-jquery-plugin/)

Simple to use and even you can customize it .