# How to show more information, when user hovers?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, tooltip

I have an info icon which when the user hovers over, is able to see more information. The icons are pngs and I DO NOT want to change the position of the image, so is there any idea about using tooltips with images in my case? I also would like the tooltip to look like this:

[Example Tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O77CF.png)

This is my HTML:

```
                    <div class="modeHolder">
                        <div class="toggle">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mode">
                            <p>Ipad Mode</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infoIcon">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/info.png" alt="info icon"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="settings">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/settings.png" alt="settings icon"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modeHolder">
                        <div class="toggle">
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="slider round"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mode">
                            <p>Mac Mode</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="infoIcon">
                            <a href="#" src="images/info.png" alt="info icon"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="settings"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance

Codepen: https://codepen.io/D4SH13/pen/jOmOWqb

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure what the problem is - could you put your code into a working snippet so we can see what is working so far/what you've already tried - I don't see any tooltip information in the code for example, and we'd need to see the (relevant) CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: https://codepen.io/D4SH13/pen/jOmOWqb , sorry it was a bit late

Comment: Why don't you use the `title` property? `<img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_151567.png" alt="info icon" title="more information here">`

Comment: Better to put a proper SO snippet into your question, but what have you tried - have you considered attribute title and/or info such as is given in [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719294/how-to-change-the-style-css-of-a-tooltip and there are probably more questions like this, have a look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st:** Using `Title` tag in `<img>` element.

```
<div class="infoIcon">
    <a href="#">
        <img title="Extra Info" src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_151567.png" alt="info icon" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**Final Code**

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/gautam25raj/pen/poPoeNy

**2nd:** Using `<span>` element.

Take a `<span>` element and put it inside your tootltip container.

```
<div class="infoIcon">
    <a href="#" src="images/info.png" alt="info icon"></a>
    <!-- New span element -->
    <span class="extraInfo">Extra Info</span>
</div>
```

Make the `<span>` `postion: absolute` relative to your tooltip container `position: relative` and add some styles to `<span>` element.

```
.infoIcon {
    position: relative;
}

.extraInfo {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now, change the visibility of the span element. So that it can stay hidden until the tooltip is hovered.
`visibility: hidden;`

i.e.

```
.extraInfo{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Now, when your tooltip is hover make the span element visible.

```
.infoIcon:hover .extraInfo {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**Final Code**

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/gautam25raj/pen/xxdxgrO

**Hope this solves your problem**

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish I can up vote your post, but I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Thank you man. I can understand because i'm also new here.