# Bootstrap Tooltips with different styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tooltips showing using data-toggle like in,

```
 <i class="fa fa-fire fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Fire Place"></i>
```

I have styled the tooltips here using,

```
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {

padding: 15px;
font-size: 120%;
background-color: #FFEB6C;
color: #374D40;}
```

I'd like tooltips on different places to look different like the background color. i.e I want multiple looks for tooltips. but I don't see how I can set custom tooltip styles for each tooltip. I can't set a css class to each tooltip either since there's no such element,I'm setting tooltips through data-toggle.

Is there any way I can make this work? Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked before. You can't do it with the official plugin, but it's not hard to make it work if you want to edit the source.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/2htZe/

Comment: You can't do this with the default bootstrap tooltip. However, this is possible with this tooltipster - http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170357/dynamically-add-a-class-to-bootstraps-popover-container or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639708/modifying-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip-colors-based-on-position/20880312#20880312

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip Colors Based on Position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639708/modifying-twitter-bootstraps-tooltip-colors-based-on-position)

Answer (score 4):

Simple, I created a class to hold those CSS style called `custom-tooltip`:

```
/* Tooltip */

.custom-tooltip+.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #FFEB6C;
  color: #374D40;
}


/* Tooltip on bottom */

.custom-tooltip+.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFEB6C;
}
```

```js
$('i[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  animated: 'fade',
  placement: 'bottom'
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip */

.custom-tooltip+.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #FFEB6C;
  color: #374D40;
}


/* Tooltip on top */
.custom-tooltip+.tooltip.top>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-top: 5px solid #FFEB6C;
}


/* Tooltip on bottom */
.custom-tooltip+.tooltip.bottom>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #FFEB6C;
}


/* Tooltip on left */
.custom-tooltip+.tooltip.left>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-left: 5px solid #FFEB6C;
}


/* Tooltip on right */
.custom-tooltip+.tooltip.right>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-right: 5px solid #FFEB6C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<i class="fa fa-fire fa-lg custom-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Fire Place"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared a quite universal solution for the bootstrap 3 tooltips' styling working with the dynamically created elements. It will work also in a case when a tooltip is generated not as a sibling to its element, but on a higher level of DOM, for example when a custom `container` option has been used:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" title="Tooltip text">Hover over me</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The tooltip's `<div>` will be generated there as a sibling to `<div>`, instead of `<button>`...

**Solution**

Let's make the template option of the Bootstrap tooltip object dynamic:

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.tip = function () {
    var template;
    var $e = this.$element;
    var o  = this.options;
    if (!this.$tip) {
        template = typeof o.template == 'function' ? o.template.call($e[0]) :  o.template;
        this.$tip = $(template);
        if (this.$tip.length != 1) {
            throw new Error(this.type + ' `template` option must consist of exactly 1 top-level element!');
        }
    }
    return this.$tip;
}
```

Prepare the tooltip template function. It will get all "tooltip-*" classes from the element with tooltip and append to the "tooltip-arrow" and "tooltip-inner" divs

```
tooltipTemplate = function () {
    var classList = ($(this).attr('class')||"").split(/\s+/);
    var filterTooltipPrefix = function(val){
        return val.startsWith('tooltip-');
    };
    var tooltipClasses = classList.filter(filterTooltipPrefix).join(' ');
    return '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow ' + tooltipClasses +'"></div><div class="tooltip-inner ' + tooltipClasses +'"></div></div>';
}
```

Ensure our function works in older browsers:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
        position = position || 0;
        return this.substr(position, searchString.length) === searchString;
    };
}
```

Now enable the tooltips:

```
$('body').tooltip({ 
    selector: "[title]", 
    html: true,
    template: tooltipTemplate
});
```

Example:

`HTML`

```
<h1>Test tooltip styling</h1>
<div><span title="Long-long-long tooltip doesn't fit the single line">Hover over me 1</span></div>
<div><span class="tooltip-left" data-container="body" title="Example (left aligned):<br>Tooltip doesn't fit the single line, and is not a sibling">Hover over me 2</span></div>
<div><span class="tooltip-large tooltip-left" title="Example (left aligned):<br>This long text we want to have in the single line">Hover over me 3</span></div>
```

`CSS`

```
.tooltip-inner.tooltip-large {
    max-width: 300px;
}

.tooltip-inner.tooltip-left {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here is working demo: https://www.bootply.com/Mz48qBWXFu

**Note** I was not able to run this code on jsfiddle, which uses Bootstrap 4. It throws an error:
`TOOLTIP: Option "template" provided type "function" but expected type "string"`
Apparently some additional tweaking is necessary there.

---

**UPDATE**

Everything above was an overkill in 2 places:

Instead of posting the tooltip styling classes in the class property of an element, it is better to use a `data-` property. That would simplify the `tooltipTemplate` function and remove the `startsWith` code shim:

```
tooltipTemplate = function () {
    var tooltipClasses = $(this).data('tooltip-custom-classes');
    return '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow ' + tooltipClasses +'"></div><div class="tooltip-inner ' + tooltipClasses +'"></div></div>';
}
```

Much more important, we don't need to modify tooltip template at all.
We should have a callback to the `inserted.bs.tooltip` event. That would simplify everything (thanks go to Oleg for his answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994192/9921853):

`Bootstrap 3:`

```
$(document).on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(e.target).data('bs.tooltip');
    tooltip.$tip.addClass($(e.target).data('tooltip-custom-class'));
});
```

`Bootstrap 4:`

```
$(document).on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(e.target).data('bs.tooltip');
    $(tooltip.tip).addClass($(e.target).data('tooltip-custom-class'));
});
```

Here are the whole examples:
[for Bootstrap 3](https://www.bootply.com/UORR04ncTP)
[for Bootstrap 4](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/naq530hx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<i id="my-tooltip-1" class="fa fa-fire fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Fire Place"></i>

<style>
#my-tooltip-1 + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 120%;
        background-color: #FFEB6C;
        color: #374D40;

        /* do something */
}
#my-tooltip-1 + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow {
        background-color: #FFEB6C;

        /* do something */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I too have been searching** (far and wide) for an answer to **apply different styles to selective tooltips** in **Bootsrap 4** and to say I was getting ***frustrated*** is an understatement.

Lots of threads simply address styling global .tooltip-inner or using scripting to accomplish this, even Bootstrap probably should have provided a simpler way.

*Anyhow here's my own personal scenario & workaround.*

I generally stick to the basic Bootstrap tooltip options (*I assume this is working already*, otherwise see update below) for various tooltips appearing on pages, but on my Navbar I have a keyboard shortcut Favicon in an anchor tag which I wanted to style. The way I accomplished this is by **wrapping it in a span** tag (or "data-container" as George put it [see credits]).

```
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js'/>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js'/>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'/>

<nav>
...
<span class="tt_kb">
<a class="nav-item nav-link px-2" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"  placement="auto"  data-html="true" container="body" trigger="hover" data-container=".tt_kb" data-boundary="window" title="Keyboard Shortcuts ... blah blah blah"><i class="far fa-keyboard"></i></a>
</span>
...
</nav>

<style>
.tt_kb .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #3266FF;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    right: 50px;
}
</style>
```

The odd thing for me is that ***for some reason*** the [**position="auto"**] ***didn't work*** (well) as I have the tt_kb Favicon on the top right hand side of the Navbar, *half of the tooltip was disappearing outside my window*, hence I ***added*** [**position:relative** & **right:50px**] in the CSS to get around this. Overall this worked reasonably well for me and I suppose with a little tweaking you could get this to work in your scenario.

Hope this help )

---

**credits**: Idea came from **George**'s "*Using a custom style for each tooltip*" commnent on thread [stackoverflow/questions/re-color-tooltip-in-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143382/re-color-tooltip-in-bootstrap-4) which sadly I could not even mark as useful of comment on due to me being new without reputation (

---

**UPDATE**

For those who don't have the general Bootstrap/Popper tooltips working you may want to add the following script & general styles to your code.

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });

      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(){
        var options = {
          html: true
        };

        if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('data-type')) {
            options['template'] =
              '&#60;div class="tooltip ' + $(this).attr('data-type') + '" role="tooltip"&#62;' +
              ' &#60;div class="tooltip-arrow"&#62;&#60;/div&#62;' +
              ' &#60;div class="tooltip-inner"&#62;&#60;/div&#62;' +
              '&#60;/div&#62;';
        }

        $(this).tooltip(options);
    });
    </script>

</style>
  .tooltip.primary .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #31b0d5; }
  .tooltip.primary.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #337ab7; }
  .tooltip.primary.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #337ab7; }
  .tooltip.primary.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #337ab7; }
  .tooltip.primary.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #337ab7; }

  .tooltip.info .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #31b0d5; }
  .tooltip.info.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #31b0d5; }
  .tooltip.info.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #31b0d5; }
  .tooltip.info.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #31b0d5; }
  .tooltip.info.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #31b0d5; }

  .tooltip.success .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #449d44; }
  .tooltip.success.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #449d44; }
  .tooltip.success.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #449d44; }
  .tooltip.success.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #449d44; }
  .tooltip.success.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #449d44; }

  .tooltip.warning .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #ec971f; }
  .tooltip.warning.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #ec971f; }
  .tooltip.warning.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #ec971f; }
  .tooltip.warning.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #ec971f; }
  .tooltip.warning.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #ec971f; }

  .tooltip.danger .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #d9534f; }
  .tooltip.danger.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #d9534f; }
  .tooltip.danger.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #d9534f; }
  .tooltip.danger.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #d9534f; }
  .tooltip.danger.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #d9534f; }
</style>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Added fully working [**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tangoairo/hkjfv0aq/23/)

**NB** For some reason the Navbar won't align right in the demo unless you view it zoomed at **110**% or **125**%!