# Why bootstrap's tooltip JavaScript initialization is necessary for custom style?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I wanted to change default style of the bootstrap's tooltip, and i was able to do that after following [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h) article. That article as well as other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color) suggest to use something like below

```
/* Tooltip on top */
  .test + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow {
      border-top: 5px solid green;
  }
```

which means i have to add `test` class on tooltip element. But i want all the tooltips to have same style so i decided not to add `test` class

My working  [JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/037pjygv/3/)

However, in order to get custom styling working i have to initialize toolips using javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

If i remove this javascript, tooltips still works but does not show custom styling.

So tooltip works regardless if i initialize it using javascript or not, however custom styling only works if initialize it using javascript. Why?

Answer (score 0):

From [Boostrap - Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips):

> **Opt-in functionality**
>
> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.

Comment: but tooltip still works even if you dont opt-in. If we just add `title` attribute to any html element it shows tooltip without opt-in

Comment: Tooltip is a default feature even without Bootstrap. The team of Bootstrap preferred to opt-in the use of a customization in 'tooltip' avoiding doing it automatically.