# Setting different attributes to tooltips

Tags: css, tooltip

I am giving different settings for tool tips. It's not working.

```css
    .hi .tooltip-inner {
        background: #00f;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="hi">
        <a class="tooltips" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body" data-original-title="Hi there" href="#">Hi there</a>
    </div>
        <div class="hello">
        <a class="tooltips" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body" data-original-title="Hello" href="#">Hello</a>
    </div>
```

I am setting the background of 'hi there' to blue, but not working. What's wrong?

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. `.tooltip-inner` doesn't exist in the HTML you provided either. Can you post the rest of the code (either the JS or CSS that controls the rest of the tooltips)? I'm fairly certain what the issue is, but don't want to post an answer until I'm sure what the markup is.

Comment: What related libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using boostrap tooltips. It would be fairly common?

Comment: @Gene9y `.tooltip-inner` this selector doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change bootstrap tooltip color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```css
.blue-tooltip  + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #00f;}
.blue-tooltip  + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:#00f; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="hi">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Hi there" class="tooltips blue-tooltip">Hi there</a>
 </div>
    <div class="hello">
     <a class="tooltips" data-placement="bottom"  data-toggle="tooltip"  data-original-title="Hello" href="#">Hello</a>
 </div>
</div>
```