# Referencing trigger from generated tooltip HTML

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to customize the generated tooltip HTML depending on what element triggers it, but I have no way of telling which one did once the tooltip is shown.

I can't use `data-container` with an id either because there are multiple of these trigger elements.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/)

Comment: Can you please give us something to work on? like a fiddle or whatever. Thanks.

Comment: @briosheje sure: https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/

Comment: is `data-container` mandatory?

Comment: @briosheje these tooltips are displayed within a modal, so I am using `data-container` to make sure they are rendered within that container, otherwise they will show up hidden behind it because of `z-index`.

Comment: it seems the data-container is creating the issue. If you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642447/change-bootstrap-tooltip-color And try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/16/ you may notice that without data-container your code will work. I've updated your fiddle to prove the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/1/ . If you can create a proper CSS selector you can surely make it work with data-container as well, but I'm not really a css master... so.. Maybe this will still help you.

Comment: Otherwise, you can use this javascript solution: https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/2/ . This will apply the css class of the data-tooltip-class attribute to the inner tooltip item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the two solutions, you can probably work on this one, where through the bootstrap 3's `inserted.bs.tooltip` event you can customize the tooltip.

```
$(document).on('inserted.bs.tooltip', function(e) {
    var tooltip = $(e.target).data('bs.tooltip');
    tooltip.$tip.find('.tooltip-inner').addClass($(e.target).data('tooltip-class'));
});
```

the `.find` part is relevant, since it targets the proper element.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/2/

EDIT:

Updated fiddle, suggested by the OP in order to work with the arrow styling as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/3/

Comment: Amazing, that's a pretty smart solution. Just change your jsfiddle to this: https://jsfiddle.net/eqsLp8gt/3/ so the arrow also changes color.