# glyphicon and customized tooltip bootstrap 3

Tags: css

I have below code which represents tooltip for the glyphicon, i.e when user hovers mouse on glyphicon. but I would like to do customization of tooltip like chaing color to red increasing size of the tooltip box etc. here is the code which is embedded besides label of bootstrap.

```
<i class="fa-info-circle" title="test"></i>
```

Can i add customized CSS class which would do the job like below

```
  <i class="mycustomizedclass fa-info-circle" title="test"></i>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes but it does not work for me

Comment: Then you'll need to post a [mcve] in your question demonstrating the problem.

Comment: you should definitely check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/17642447/10956327