# Change style of bootstrap popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'd like to use the default bootstrap styles for a popover (primary success, info, warning and danger).

Does anybody knows how can I use these styles in a popover?

Ps.: the styles should be selected dynamically, based on the status of the popover element.

Comment: You could also use the `template` parameter of popovers to add classes onto the popover.

Comment: @cvrebert, I need to apply different styles to different popovers in the same page. So, i need to apply the style in the element.

Comment: Check on @yuvi solution on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170357/dynamically-add-a-class-to-bootstraps-popover-container

Answer (score -2):

you have to edit the less file if you want to replace the color anywhere

on the side you can customize your css file with the colors you want.

link: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#colors

Comment: This answer isn't related to the question, as I asked about dynamic styles on popover and not about how to change color customizing css.