# Give a bootstrap popover an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to add a class or ID to a bootstrap popover?

Now, whenever I get a popover, it has the generic class `popover`, so I cannot style it individually.

```
<a href="#;" class="hover-dropdown" data-placement="bottom" 
   data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-content="hello">Hello</a>
```

How would I give the popup this creates a class or ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867792/20126 or use the .popover selector to get the popover and add an id to it