# How to add a class to a popover title

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the popover's bootstrap element but I don't know how to attribute to it a class. I'd like to create a customed background color for each different class.
Here's my popover build (in javascript)

```
$(element).popover({
                    'placement': 'top',
                    'animation': true,
                    'html': true,
                    'title' : variable,
                    'content': html
                });

                $(element).popover('show');
```

If I do :

```
$(element).popover({
                    'placement': function(context, src) {
                        $(context).addClass($(src).data('customClassName'));
                        return 'top';},
                    'animation': true,
                    'html': true,
                    'title' :feature.get('features')[0].get('name') + ' (' +  feature.get('features')[0].get('type') + ')',
                    'content': html
                });
                $(element).popover().addClass('TESTCLASS');
                $(element).popover('show');
```

The result given will be 
[image]

As you can see the class is not in the same div that the popover-title

Comment: $(element).popover().addClass('yourclass')

Comment: @Raviteja the class generated is on the sibling, I have to reach the sibling then the child to get the popover-title class, my question was at first if I could add the class to the popover-title directly

Comment: can you please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170357/dynamically-add-a-class-to-bootstraps-popover-container

Comment: @HemrajJain An answer has be given but thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your custom template using `template` property:

```
function getPopoverCustomTemplate(className) {
    return '<div class="popover ' + className + '" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>';
}

$(element).popover({
    'placement': 'top',
    'animation': true,
    'html': true,
    'title' : variable,
    'content': html,
    'template': getPopoverCustomTemplate('myCustomClass')
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want, I put the class name on the popover-title class, thank you !