# Is it possible to change width for different popovers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I've two popovers on the same page, I have changed the width of a popover by

```
.popover {
  min-width: 80%;
}
```

But for the first opover I want a width of 80% and for other I need 20% width. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky subject, but it has been answered here. I don't ever mess with dynamically adding popovers, so I can't feign to know how these work.

[Dynamically add a class to Bootstrap's 'popover' container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170357/dynamically-add-a-class-to-bootstraps-popover-container/14867792#14867792)